# Category - Products [PHP , MySQL PDO]

Tags: php, html, mysql, pdo

This is my category & products SQL/PHP schema.

I need to `echo` the `<hr>` for each of my *categories* and not for each *products*.
This is my code :

```
$sql = $db->query("SELECT * from cat,products where cat.cat_id = products.cat_id order by products.cat_id desc");
while ($row = $sql->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){   
    $ID = $row["id"];
    $Title = $row["title"];
    $CatID = $row["cat_id"];

    $row["cat_id"] = $row["cat_name"];
    switch ($row["cat_id"]){
        case $row["cat_id"] == $row["cat_name"]:
            echo "<hr>";
            break;
        default:

            break;
    }

    echo $row["cat_id"];
    echo "<a href='test.php?cat=$CatID&prod=$ID'>$Title</a><br/>";
}
```

Image : 
[image]

thanks and sorry for my poor English...

Comment: `echo "hr";` you mean `echo "<hr>";`, *correct?*

Comment: yes, i can not use that from this website becase "stackoverflow.com" use that for "HTML TAG" and render that ...

Comment: I edited your question with `hr`. Just use appropriate styling.

Comment: Take a look at http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks. You should reformat question so the code is as you have it

Comment: thanks , yes i saw :* really thanks , and please edit this too : 
echo "<a href='test.php?cat=$CatID&prod=$ID'>$Title</a><br/>"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can write the following due to the fact that your SQL statement is sorted by the categories:

```
        $tmp_category = '';    

            $sql = $db->query("SELECT * from cat,products where cat.cat_id = products.cat_id order by products.cat_id desc");
                while ($row = $sql->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){  


                $ID = $row["id"];
                $Title = $row["title"];
                $CatID = $row["cat_id"];

    if ($row["cat_id"] <> $tmp_category){ //you can use  != instead of <> as well

        $tmp_category = $row["cat_id"]; 
        echo "<hr>";        
        echo $row["cat_id"];
        echo "<a href='test.php?cat=$CatID&prod=$ID'>$Title</a><br/>";

    }
    else
    {

        echo $row["cat_id"];  // this is optional, you can delete the cat ID from here and it will show you only the above link.
        echo "<a href='test.php?cat=$CatID&prod=$ID'>$Title</a><br/>";
    }


        }
```

Comment: thanks it's going true , really thanks :* :************** :X